# Delphi 4 Python

Tags: python, delphi

I want  to use  the Delphi 4 Python components  from here  https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi
but I don't want to drop the components  on a form, I want everything  in code ,  my code goes like  this :

```
 var
  PythonEngine_netA: TPythonEngine;
  PythonInputOutput_netA: TPythonInputOutput;
begin
  PythonEngine_netA := TPythonEngine.Create(Self);
  PythonInputOutput_netA := TPythonInputOutput.Create(Self);
  try
    ///  configure the components
    PythonEngine_netA.DllName:='python39.dll';
    PythonEngine_netA.IO := PythonInputOutput_netA;
    PythonEngine_netA.UseLastKnownVersion := True;

    PythonInputOutput_netA.OnSendUniData := PythonInputOutput_SendUniData;
    PythonInputOutput_netA.UnicodeIO := True;
    PythonInputOutput_netA.RawOutput := True;

    ///  execute  the script
    PythonEngine_netA.ExecString(UTF8Encode(mmo_pythoncode.text));
  finally
    PythonEngine_netA.free;
    PythonInputOutput_netA.free;
  end;
```

execution of this code fails, error msg : "Python is not properly initialized",
what did I miss  to use this code ?

Answer (score 1):

One quick look at [PythonEngine.pas](https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi/blob/master/Source/PythonEngine.pas) (or even better: always search all files for the error message to find out where and why an error is returned) tells me you missed calling `PythonEngine_netA.Initialize()`.

Also note that [/Demos](https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi/tree/master/Demos) describes:

> Demo34  Dynamically creating, destroying and recreating PythonEngine.  Uses PythonVersions

So please have a look at [/Demos/Demo34/Unit1.pas](https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi/blob/master/Demos/Demo34/Unit1.pas) how it is done there with (almost) no components. Or run the whole project in general, preferably in debug mode single stepping thru it be aware which method does what.

Comment: add  this  line  of code ,  but get now  an AV error  when calling  : PythonEngine_netA.Initialize()  command

Comment: How about debugging and single stepping execution thru that method?

Comment: error happend at  procedure TPythonEngine.AssignPyFlags; already added  this code with no success :

Comment: PythonFlags_netA : TPythonFlags ;
begin
 ..
  try
    ///  configure the components
    ///
    PythonFlags_netA:=[];

   
    ...
    PythonEngine_netA.PyFlags :=  PythonFlags_netA;

Comment: And where in that method? `Py_DebugFlag` is a pointer and is set in `TPythonInterface.MapDll` - that method is called in `TPythonInterface.AfterLoad`. And since `TPythonEngine` inherites from `TPythonInterface` call `PythonInputOutput_netA.AfterLoad()`. Also edit your question and use code formattings in your comments.

Comment: can you pls. add  the complete code sequence  in your  answer ,  did not understand where  to put  the .... .AfterLoad function  . If I drop  the components  on the form  the pythonengine  works and I did not see the need for additional  code. Also in the *.fmx  form with the  components there is no additional code  inserted

Comment: If you cannot figure out that the better way would be to run and look at how Demo #34 does it (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to load the Dll:

```
PythonEngine_netA.UseLastKnownVersion:= True;
//PythonEngine_netA.opendll(PYDLL)
PythonEngine_netA.LoadDll;
PythonEngine_netA.IO:= PythonInputOutput_netA;
```